# Rendering lots of sprites with hexagon shape from image using pixijs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I'm trying to create a hexagonal map with the list of terrain types.
At the moment I have the map that is drawn from the sprites that uses as a base texture the graphics with the shape of a hexagon.
I need to put a different images on them, but can't find a solution how to do it.

Here's the demo of what I have: https://codepen.io/cuddlemeister/pen/rPvwZw

I've tryied to do it in this way:

```
const texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(img);
const s = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
s.mask = graphics;
```

But I get only one hexagon that mask being applyied to. And if I put graphics in a loop, I get performance issues.
Maybe I should just cut the images to get hexagons and simply draw sprites made from these images?

Here's what I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUNbp.jpg

Basically, I need to replace that white hexagons with some textures. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

how about that:
https://jsfiddle.net/vxt5eqk4/
for each tile you use a clipmask

```
var scale = 8;
for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
  for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
var offsetx = (y%2)*5 + x*10 - 6;
var offsety = y * 9 -3;
ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(scale*(offsetx+5),scale*(offsety));
    ctx.lineTo(scale*(offsetx+10),scale*(offsety+3));
    ctx.lineTo(scale*(offsetx+10),scale*(offsety+9));
    ctx.lineTo(scale*(offsetx+5),scale*(offsety+12));
    ctx.lineTo(scale*offsetx,scale*(offsety+9));
    ctx.lineTo(scale*offsetx,scale*(offsety+3));
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clip();
  if((y%2 !== 0 || x%2 !== 0) && (y%2 === 0 || x%2 === 0)){
      ctx.drawImage(img, scale*offsetx, scale*offsety, 10*scale,  12*scale);
    }else{
      ctx.drawImage(img2, scale*offsetx, scale*offsety, 10*scale,  12*scale);
    }
  ctx.restore();
}
```

a 10x12 grid seemed fine to me to draw a hexagon
the fiddle just shows a basic method to draw hexagonal tiles, the if part should be replaced by getting the proper image for the tile in the tilemap, should you use one

Comment: thank you for the provided example, but that doesn't fit what is needed, as well as in pixi instead of clip method uses masking. and using masks even made from sprites causes huge performance limitations. At the moment the problem was solved by using sprites that already has shape of hexagon

Comment: when performance is concerened, cant you just render the field once and save the canvas result to a buffer and then just draw that buffer every frame?